# Vim autoindent indents incorrectly

Tags: vim, indentation

When writing code in vim, I've noticed that it sometimes messes up the indentation of the current line after pressing return.  (In the gif, I go into insert mode, with the cursor at the end of the date function. When I press return, the whole "echo date('Y');" part looses its indentation when it should not).

[image: Vim]

I have a ton of directives in my vimrc to try and stop all kinds of autoindentation, but much to my irritation, the problem persists.

```
filetype plugin indent off
filetype plugin off
set noautoindent
set nosmartindent
set nocindent
set indentexpr=''
let b:did_indent = 1
set ft?
filetype indent off
```

I wish there was a way to have vim indent files much like your "more standard" text editors, whereby they don't try to be smart, but just maintain the current indentation of the current line in the new line. Like this:

[image: Gedit]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set smartindent` is only needed on my VIM to get the effect you shown by gedit.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, this helped me make it work like gedit. However, I did have to make it the last of the indentation rules in my vimrc. It seems the others can overwrite it. The issue with the PHP tags shown in the VIM gif still persits.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that this line was causing the first issue displayed in the vim. Its part of the Vundle plugin manager inclusion code:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Ensuring that my indent rules were after this fixed the problem completely.